# how to accommodate multiple edit (design question)

Tags: asp.net, gridview

how would you handle multiple edits in a gridview?  here is the situation:

I have one (Organization) to many (domain name) relations

so one organization can have multiple domain name

my gridview looks something like this:

---

### Org Name    -  Domain Name        |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Don't know with what kind of grid you are working? A standard Microsoft grid? The  [ASPxGridView](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/ASP/Grid/Gallery.xml) from DevExpress does a great job in Master-Detail scenarios.

Comment: yea asp.net standard gridview control,

Comment: The standard asp.NET gridcontrol from Microsoft doesn't have the rich features of a DevExpress ASPx Gridview. But maybe this could be something you are looking for http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581796.aspx

Comment: Actually is this what you are looking for? Master-Detail presentation? Because out of your original question it didn't became very clear to me...